# Environment set-up android mobile application

Tags: java, android, database, ide

I have to create an android mobile application for college. On paper I have adequate modules completed to be able to do this, however I struggle with coding and simply need to complete this module to graduate.
I am going to use java to code my android application. I now need to set up an environment that can connect to a database. I have some experience using netbeans but did not pay a whole lot of attention over the years the database connectivity and usually had someone else do it for me.
My app is going to be a lottery purchasing ticket app.
My question is: What is the best IDE to use and what is the best db to use for my lottery application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can use Android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio
and for database android itself provides database: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite